# Automatically create app registration based ad admin username and password on azure active directory

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a issue, which I dont currently understand.

I have a list of different tenants 100+ and this list keeps growing.
For each of these tenants I want to automatically created an app registration that gives access to some specific api permissions.

The first time I log onto an azure portant (for each tenant) I have the following information:
UserName (Tenant Owner...)
UserPassword (Tenant Owner...)

Meaning that I have all the neccesary rights to be able to create an app registration.

What I am having trouble with is making this automatic based on a script.

When I manually do this I can see on the browser creates an App Registration using the graph API.

endpoint: **https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/myorganization/applications**

headers:
**application/json
+
Bearer token**

**post body**

```
{
  "displayName": "TestAccount12345678",
  "spa": {
    "redirectUris": []
  },
  "publicClient": {
    "redirectUris": []
  },
  "web": {
    "redirectUris": []
  },
  "signInAudience": "AzureADMyOrg",
  "requiredResourceAccess": [
    {
      "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
      "resourceAccess": [
        {
          "id": "e1fe6dd8-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "type": "Scope"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**My Code**
So far I have tried this:

libraries:

```
import * as msRestNodeAuth from '@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth';
import { ResourceManagementClient } from '@azure/arm-resources';
```

```
        let creds = await msRestNodeAuth.loginWithUsernamePassword(config.ServiceAccount, config.ServicePassword);
        const ressourceCli = new ResourceManagementClient(creds, config.SubScriptionID);

        let exists = await ressourceCli.resourceGroups.checkExistence(config.ResGrp);

        let accessToken = await creds.getToken();
        console.log(accessToken);

        let body = {
            displayName: 'TestAppRegistration',
            spa: { redirectUris: [] },
            publicClient: { redirectUris: [] },
            web: { redirectUris: [] },
            signInAudience: 'AzureADMyOrg',
            requiredResourceAccess: [{ resourceAppId: '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000', resourceAccess: [{ id: 'e1fe6dd8-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', type: 'Scope' }] }],
        };


        let rest = await fetch('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/myorganization/applications', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken.accessToken}` },
        });
```

When I run this code, I get an 401 error that the bearer token is not valid, as a quick note, the variable **exist** has access to azure, as it correctly tells me if a random ressource grp exists.

If I inspect the browser when creating the registration manually, and hardcode the bearer token from there, I have no issues running this code and creating the app registration.

I have also tried looking into using this library:

```
import { Client, ClientOptions } from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client';
```

But no matter how I turn it, the issues seems to be that to authenticate to the graph API I need an app registration... I need an app registration to create an app registration... and I am trying to do it based on my username and password.

On another note, I have managed to make this run on powershell: But I really dont want to run powershell to do this.

```
$connectionCustomer = Connect-AzAccount
$customerContext = Get-AzContext
Set-AzContext -Context $customerContext
AzureADApp = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $createNewAppName
```

Is there anything I am missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use one multi-tenant app? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant

Comment: According to your code, it seems that you wanna use graphapi to create azure ad application in each tenant, and I found the api document of [creating application](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), it works well when I try to create app in my tenant. So when you want to use it to create app in different tenant, that means you need a multi-tenant app in each tenant so that you can generate access token for creating app in each tenant. But if you've had a multi-tenant app in all tenant, you dont need to create any more.

Comment: That's what @juunas said, what you need to do is creating a multi-tenant app in one tenant, and add enough api permission, then calling this requestion( h tt ps://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id} ) to make the app active in all tenants, then you can achieve your goal.

Comment: @Jbb4Play Could you please try to parse your token vai https://jwt.ms

Answer (score 0):

Hello everybody and thanks for all the good feedback.

I have gone ahead and used a multi tenant app, which grants me the correct privilege's.
My purpose was to do some management, and access the graph api, and thats to this, it has been done.

Code snippets:

```
const msalConfig: msal.Configuration = {
            auth: {
                clientId: AdminClientID,
                authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${adalToken.tenantId}`,
                clientSecret: 'secret',
            },
        };

        let pca = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
        // see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#device-code for alternative code flows
        let tokenObj = await pca.acquireTokenByUsernamePassword({ scopes: [], password: config.CustomerPassword, username: config.CustomerAccount });
        if (!tokenObj) {
            return;
        }

        let action: IManager = new AzureAppRegistrationManager(tokenObj.accessToken);

        await action.verifyAndCreate();
```